# What does `%20` mean in a Flutter import?

Tags: flutter, dart

My code editor imported `flutter_bloc` as shown in the code below with a `%20` and it works.

```
import 'package:fluent_ui/fluent_ui.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart%20';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:qmt_manager/logic/values.dart';
```

What does `%20` in the import mean?

Comment: %20 is a space character.

Comment: You can probably safely remove it, it doesn't make much sense for a package name to end with a space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%20` is the URL encoding for a space character:

[image]

Let's say you visit:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flutter
```

and type in a space after the word `tagged` in the URL and reload, and there will be a space after the word `tagged`:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged%20/flutter
```

---

I have tried to import `material.dart` by adding `%20` but the file couldn't be found:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart%20';
```

Now, to fix the import - which you should also for the case that other developers will run your code and will result in an error.

To fix the *bloc* import, I'd suggest running:

```
flutter clean
```

and

```
flutter pub get
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `%20` is the URL-encoding representation for a space character, while `20` being the hex representation of the ASCII encoding for the space.

Comment: It's android studio that imported it to me it was my first time to see it in flutter, I was wondering if it had a particular meaning, maybe an update of flutter but no